# How to sort Multi-Dimensional Arrays in PHP where Keys are actually Values

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array, unique

I have a multi-dimensional array shown below that I want to sort by the 1st level dimension and then the 2nd level dimension within the 1st level.

I want the dates to be in chronological order and then then times, within the dates, to be in clock sequence.

```
Array
(
    [2014-05-17] => Array
        (
            [0] => 17:30
            [1] => 11:30
            [2] => 13:30
            [3] => 12:30
            [4] => 12:30
        )

    [2014-06-21] => Array
        (
            [0] => 17:30
            [1] => 10:30
            [2] => 13:30
            [3] => 09:30
            [4] => 12:30
            [5] => 09:30
            [6] => 12:30
        )

    [2014-05-18] => Array
        (
            [0] => 17:30
            [1] => 11:30
            [2] => 13:30
            [3] => 12:30
            [4] => 12:30
        )
)
```

Also, after I sort the times, I want to remove duplicates -- in other words I simply want the unique times within each date to be in clock order.

**Here is what I would like to produce:**

[2014-05-17] => Array
    (
        [0] => 11:30
        [1] => 12:30
        [2] => 13:30
        [3] => 17:30
    )

[2014-05-18] => Array
    (
        [0] => 11:30
        [1] => 12:30
        [2] => 13:30
        [3] => 17:30
    )

[2014-06-21] => Array
    (
        [0] => 09:30
        [1] => 10:30
        [2] => 12:30
        [3] => 13:30
        [4] => 17:30
    )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your variable array name is $arrayDate, execute this:

```
ksort($arrayDate);
foreach($arrayDate as &$key){
    $key = array_unique($key);
    sort($key);
}
```

Comment: It simply produced `Array
(
    [0] => 11:30
    [1] => 13:30
)` @AlbertoDelgado

Comment: Your array, date index must be quoted, for example '2014-05-17', add quotes and try code again